# Sitecore Html helper Dynamic Placeholder doesn't accept more than 1 arguments

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-forms

I'm working with Sitecore MVC. I have a problem with my sitecore html helper. when I call `@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("placeholderKey")` it will work successfully but, when I try adding some arguments it will not work.

> **Error message** : No overload for method 'DynamicPlaceholder' takes 3 arguments.

It just the DynamicPlaceholder with single argument works other overloading methods won't.

Please help me. It's been a struggle.

My Sample use of Dynamic Placeholder :

[image]

Output screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Note : even this line is error @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("feature_spot", CreateDivWrap(), 3)

Comment: Which Sitecore version you use?

Comment: I'm working with Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore `Dynamic Placeholders` were introduced in Sitecore 9. You can read about it e.g. here:

https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/sitecore-9-dynamic-placeholders/

As you wrote in your comment, you're using **Sitecore 8.2**.

It means that you're using some custom implementation of Dynamic Placeholders and you're trying to use methods which are only in Sitecore 9 ( https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/dynamic-placeholders.html ). That's why you see compilation errors.

Comment: I am deleting my answer because doesn't bring any value.is funny we post same link .

Comment: Kamruz blog post is so famous that it gets very high in Google search results :)

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I hope I can find a way to custom implement the Dynamic Placeholder.

Comment: Marek Musielak, Why I'm getting a suggestion of DynamicPlaceholder overload menthods ? but, when i run the site it will display the same error..

Comment: I can only suspect that the referenced dlls and dlls in bin folder don't match. There is no way to validate that without sitting in front of your laptop